# get_CurrentTransaction in InMemory.TransactionManager does not have an implementation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core application that implements the InMemoryDatabase for integration testing. I'm following the instructions from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing).

Basically it shows how to configure the service (in Startup.cs) using the AddDbContext method which is what I did and I make the call to UseInMemoryDatabase:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {        
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAssetRepository, AssetRepository>();
    }
```

My AppDbContext is defined in another project in the solution and is defined as such:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> dbContextOptions) :
        base(dbContextOptions)
    {            
    }

    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TodoItem> Todos { get; set; }
}
```

Back to the Startup.cs file, according to the link I need to code the Configure method like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            var repository = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAssetRepository>();
            InitializeDatabaseAsync(repository).Wait();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

This snippet runs ok and executes the call to GetService. This call runs the constructor for AppDbContext but the constructor crashes with the folling exception. It crashes when calling the base constructor: base(dbContextOptions).

> Method 'get_CurrentTransaction' in type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTransactionManager'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory,
>   Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   does not have an implementation.

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this exception. Can someone give me some direction?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

After some more investigating, I found out that this error occurred because the project that contains the configuration code (Startup.cs) had a reference to version 1.0.1 of "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory".

However, I changed it to 1.1.0 and it suddenly worked. So I'm assuming that the implementation was added to version 1.1.0.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: I'm now getting the same error with v2.0.1 of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory and find that rolling back to v2.0.0 resolves it. Deja vu.